# Array of references to child objects failed to initialize

Tags: java, oop

I need to create array of references to child objects. In this case Room has to have array of references to objects: `DarkRoom` and `LightRoom`. Having error in line where initialization of array of type `Room`. What's missing?

```
public abstract class Room {

    public Room[][] space = new Room[4][4]; // <<Syntax error on token ";",

    space[0][0] = new DarkRoom();
    space[0][1] = new LightRoom();
    space[1][0] = new DarkRoom();
    space[1][1] = new LightRoom();              
}

public class LightRoom extends Room  { ... }

public class DarkRoom extends Room  { ... }
```

Comment: The next lines are wrong. Put in one method!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your design is way off the mark. A class should not hold an array of child objects and in fact should have no knowledge about or dependence on its child classes. This is both a recursive and a logical nightmare.

I suggest you remove the array from within the Room class to somewhere more appropriate, such as the Hotel class or House class.

Comment: +1 funny, didn't answer the question, yet the best answer here :)

Comment: Certainly a better long term solution than correcting the syntax.

Answer (score 4):

The initialization should not be done outside an initialization block or method, instead, do:

```
public Room[][] space = new Room[4][4];
{
    space[0][0] = new DarkRoom();
    space[0][1] = new LightRoom();
    space[1][0] = new DarkRoom();
    space[1][1] = new LightRoom();
}
```

Comment: Do braces define the body of constructor of Room?

Answer (score 4):

It's complaining about the space[][] blocks.  You can't just write code into your class definition.

```
public abstract class Room {

  public Room[][] space = new Room[4][4]; // << error Syntax error on token ";",

  public Room()
  {
    space[0][0] = new DarkRoom();
    space[0][1] = new LightRoom();
    space[1][0] = new DarkRoom();
    space[1][1] = new LightRoom();
  }
  }
```